# In Postgres, is there a need to lock a row in a table using FOR UPDATE if the query is contained in a transaction with serializable isolation level?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In Postgres, is there a need to lock a row in a table using FOR UPDATE if the query is contained in a transaction with serializable isolation level? In other words, does serializable transaction lock the rows by itself until the transaction is committed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question. The answer is that you don't *need* to use `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` to avoid anomalies (effects of race conditions) on the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, but that it can still be useful to lock rows explicitly to avoid serialization errors.

The design principle of `SERIALIZABLE` is that you don't have to worry about what concurrent transactions do: you are guaranteed that if your transaction succeeds, the result will be safe from race conditions. To achieve that, the database can abort your transaction with a *serialization error* if it cannot think of any other way to keep that promise. If that happens, you have to retry the transaction until it succeeds.

To provide a concrete example: if a concurrent transaction modifies a table row between the time your transaction reads the row and the time it tries to update the row, you will receive a serialization error. If that is a frequent occurrence, it can be quite annoying, because it means that you will have to retry the transaction frequently. This is bad for your overall performance.

In such situations, it can be useful to explicitly lock the row against concurrent modifications using `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` (yes, that is the correct lock if you intend to `UPDATE`; `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is only appropriate if you intend to `DELETE` the row or to update a column with a unique constraint). Such *pessimistic locking* will reduce concurrency, but can avoid the serialization error, so it can be a good choice for highly contended data.

Comment: Good short answer and straight to the point.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean to write "transaction is committed" rather than "transaction is completed"?

Please be aware that isolation levels are enforced, and anomalies avoided, only when committing transactions.  By default, auto-commit is ON, which means that a COMMIT command is run automatically after you execute a SQL command/transaction or set of transactions.  If this is OFF, then all of your transactions must be batched with a COMMIT at the end of each, in order for the transaction level to function as documented by Postgres.  The commit basically puts all transactions in a system/Postgres table in sequence before actually being run.

Also be aware that isolation levels exist simply to allow transactions to be executed in parallel (at the same time) by different sessions/users.  So this is when locks are necessary.  If you build your application code to call database code to run things in sequence/serialized, then isolation levels are not even needed.  They call the isolation level serializable, so that everything is in the actual sequence/serial of when it actually executed, by any session, based on the system timestamp.  According to @Laurenz Albe, there are other factors that determine execution besides commit timestamp.  If you have a web application for example, then multiple sessions will exist, and sometimes even with the same user, while changing data "almost" simultaneously (since nothing is actually in parallel in the database world), then isolation levels are critical.

Database locks are handled by Postgres correctly (theoretically if source code is 100% perfect) based on the isolation level.  Serializable is the most strict, so the ***thousands of different anomaly scenarios*** that are possible (of the four categories), should be avoided, and locks handled properly.  But we all know that software is rarely perfect.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

It is too difficult to answer whether FOR UPDATE will be handled correctly without testing.  Take a look at this article.

http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2011/01/locking-in-postgresql.html

As an alternative to using isolation levels, you can implement your own locks using explicit locking.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html

Scenarios that often cause issues with serializable are when primary and foreign keys are not implemented.  Or when indexes are partially committed for data in a table, because the dataset is so large and an index is still building.  So referential integrity is a must if dealing with serializable.
In the past, I had dealt with a hierarchy of over 200K records and locks were needed in the middle of a hierarchy (soft coded not hard coded--meaning the parent and child ids are in the same table).  This is when locks are NOT handled properly in Postgres, because the isolation level depends on the structure Postgres designed, not designs commonly used in the real world.  So in that case, FOR UPDATE will not lock properly, not because Postgres "behind the scenes" code is wrong, but because the meaning of a primary/foreign key relationship of a soft coded hierarchy table does not conform to recommended practices by Postgres.

What I'd recommend is reading through and implementing best practices based on the PostgreSQL documentation and especially your database backup procedures.  Also test actual database restores from a backup and test the referential integrity of the database after this is done.  This will likely be the culprit of future issues with this isolation level, rather than your SQL code itself.

So yes, serializable isolation "should" handle the row level lock, under these contingencies.

Comment: Serializable transactions run in series one after another and not in parallel. So why would I need a lock on a row if no other transaction can change the data while the serializable transaction is running and then is committed?

Comment: Correct.  You do not need to worry if you can execute all of your application SQL commands/transactions in order.  The reason isolation levels exist is for multi-user or multi-session applications and you may be touching the same data in the same command or running things in near-parallel (ie: highlighting multiple SQL commands before executing code in pgadmin, in a batch for example may run multiple SQL transactions on the same record).  Isolation levels offers intelligence to this without human intervention.

Comment: I think that this answer is more confusing than helpful. For example, serializable isolation is *not* only enforced at commit time.

Comment: Feel free to answer.  I was trying to help.